# VLAN in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

How to add VLAN in ubuntu 18.04 throuth GUI?
In 16 was window with selection type interfaces to add, in 18 just "+" and opened window with new profile adding

Comment: `nm-connection-editor` found on xubuntu